# Setting up Cloned site on Local Host

Tags: php, debugging, magento, localhost, wamp

Hey I recently set up a local server for my Magento 1.14.2.2 live site for testing.

I change out the app/ect/config.xml file and the local.xml file so that my localhost info is correct, and up until today it has worked fine every time.

For some reason out of nowhere, it no longer is working and when I try to view my frontend on my local host I am receiving an error:

**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1866162951**

When I go inspect the var/report/1866162951 file I am getting the following lines:

> a:5:{i:0;s:307:"Error in file: 
>   "C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\local\Amasty\PromoBannersLite\sql\ambannerslite_setup\mysql4-install-1.0.0.php"
>   - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ambannerslite_setup' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `core_resource` (`code`, `version`) VALUES (?, ?)";i:1;s:884:"#0
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...') 1
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '',
>   '1.0.5') 2
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.0.5') 3
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates() 4
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() 5
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() 6
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 7
>   C:\wamp1\www\sgk\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') 8
>   {main}";s:3:"url";s:5:"/sgk/";s:11:"script_name";s:14:"/sgk/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Can someone please tell me what this report is telling me so that I am able to get my local host back up and running?

Thanks

Comment: from the log it appears something is attempting to insert into a table where that value already exists. you may have to re-migrate your data or Trunc some tables  to make sure it can insert that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to mysql ( maybe phpmyadmin) . Select your database, paste and run following command:

```
DELETE from core_resoure where code like '%ambanner%';
```

It may solve your current issue